# Remove text before certain string including the string using batch command

Tags: command-line, batch

I have text file which has millions of lines. I want to remove all text before a string `test:` including string. Also want to remove text after space.

**Some content from file:**

```
file1:test:src/draw/no/ind/erefe.c/gegegewg 1
filesdsd:test:src/draw/no/ind/reryeryrey.c/jhrtjtrj 1
fileskdk:sdsD:test:abc/disp/no/ind/ryretyrey.txt/Display::Restrict 20
```

**Desired output:**

```
src/draw/no/ind/erefe.c/gegegewg
src/draw/no/ind/reryeryrey.c/jhrtjtrj
abc/disp/no/ind/ryretyrey.txt/Display::Restrict
```

I have got below code which removes text after `/` from file and also echos line on command line as it has `echo`.

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=/" %a in (abc.txt) do (echo %a >> newfile.txt)
```

I want to modify above code to get above mentioned desired output. But without printing lines on cmd as it takes much time.

Comment: You said you have echo on... if you want to hide the lines to make it quicker, turn echo off. Alternatively, do the whole thing in Notepad++ with a macro or some regex.

Comment: Might be able to work with the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796707/how-to-extract-text-after-in-batch-file

Comment: What should happen to the lines that don't have ":test"?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice this question was from 5 years ago....

Answer (score 0):

There is your command:

```
cut -d " " -f1 file.txt | sed -e '1,$s/^\(.*\):test:\(.*\)$/\2/' > new_file.txt
```

or if you can modify the original file:

```
sed -i '1,$s/^\(.*\):test:\(.*\) .*$/\2/' file.txt
```

Update: I haven't noticed that the question was for Windows platform. However there is also sed for Windows, which can be installed several ways:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe

Comment: I think this sed  to be installed. Would be nice if output gets with batch. If you know, please tell me from where should I install sed.

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad Sorry, the Windows platform wasn't apparent. I've updated the answer with options of sed installation on Windows. In Linux distributions, sed is like elemental part.

Comment: It's OK. Thank you for the answer and update. I will try it.

Comment: Getting errors for both commands: `H:\New folder>"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" -i '1,$s/^\(.*\):test:\(.*\) .*$/\2/' t.txt
sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''` and `H:\New folder>cut -d " " -f1 t.txt | "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" -e '1,$s/^\(.*\):test:\(.*\)$/\2/' > new_file.txt
'cut' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: In bash under Linux it works just fine. Well, then some Windows guru, who uses sed is needed or get yourself access to some Linux distro.